# Script to stop/restart local SQL services

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Does anyone have a simple script (powershell or command line) that would enable to me to shutdown local SQL Services (SQL Server, Integration services, etc ..) when I don't need them and then perhaps another script to turn them all back on when I do need them?

Currently I am going to Services and then stopping/starting them manually.

Comment: Google has heaps http://blog.in2bi.eu/microsoft-business-intelligence/batch-file-to-start-stop-sql-server/ and http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3644906/Automatically-Stopping-and-Restarting-SQL-Server.htm and http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/managing-sql-server-services-with-powershell.html and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh403394.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a need to stop and disable and then enable and start on multiple remote servers, so this is how I handled it:

Stopping:

```
function stopdisable ($compnam, $svc)
  {
    (get-service -computername $compnam -name $svc).stop()
    set-service -computername $compnam -name $svc -startuptype disabled
  }

stopdisable "server1" "servicename1"
stopdisable "server2" "servicename2"
```

Starting:

```
function enablestart ($compnam, $svc)
  {
    set-service -computername $compnam -name $svc -startuptype automatic
    (get-service -computername $compnam -name $svc).start()
  }

enablestart "server1" "servicename1"
enablestart "server2" "servicename2"
```

Of course, this is dependent upon you having the appropriate permissions on the remote servers.

Comment: Thanks ... The server is actually local so no problems as I am the administrator. Is the above code `PowerShell`

Comment: For local, just remove the references to server name in calling the function, $compnam variable, and -computername switch from the commands.  Make sure to use the name of the service and not the displayname (ex: use "wsearch" instead of "Windows Search").